# Is it possible to disable the interlocutor's video in BlueJeans Prime?

Tags: video-calling

I use [BlueJeans Prime](https://www.bluejeans.com/) for videoconference on Android 10. When in a videoconference, is it possible to disable the interlocutor's video?

The motivation is to reduce the network usage.

---

For BlueJeans (not Prime), one can swipe up, which will activate the "low bandwidth" mode, and swipe down to go back to the normal mode. That doesn't work for BlueJeans Prime.

Comment: Have you contacted [support](https://support.bluejeans.com/s/contactsupport)? If the app really does not support it you can still place a adhesive sticker on the front camera. Less changes in the camera means less data to transmit.

Comment: @Robert thanks yes I reached out to the support and will post their reply as an answer if they reply to me. I was referring to the interlocutor video, not mine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BlueJeans' tech support told me it is not possible. They don't have any plan to support the option in the future.